# WordPress Multi-site Migration Showing 404 error on subpages

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I migrate my multisite to my live domain and now it's only showing me home page but not a single link working on that as they are showing me [Also subdomain site not working]

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /page-url/ was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I tried with permalinks switch but no luck.

my `.htaccess` is like below

```
# Block the include-only files.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**Any help?**

Answer (score -2):

When you migrated your site did you change the http references in the database? Often times that is not changed or missed and the migrated database which has lets say xyz.com/ as the pages and you changed it to abc.com/ when you migrated it from multisite. But the database still has xzy.com/ which why when it looks for abc.com/ it doesn't find it.

If this helps please rate my answer.

Comment: No there is no change related to http references in the database